# Using Fiddler:How to debug downloaded files which are generated by web application?

Tags: excel, model-view-controller, web-applications, fiddler

I have a webapplication(MVC pattern) which generates an excel file dynamically. I am already using Fiddler to monitor requests(posting json requests) to test how the webapp is faring(since UI is incomplete). 
Can I use this tool to "debug"(see if the control navigates correctly to each layer/method generating file, maybe give logs) my web app?
If this works, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence Fiddler is a debugging proxy. So you can use it to monitor the traffic generated by the browser/webserver but not what happens inside the app itself.